# How to install PySide package for CentOS 7

Tags: centos, software-installation, python

I'm trying to install PySide on CentOS 7.

Seems pretty straightforward, enable EPEL repo, and install.  Except that EPEL doesn't seem to contain a PySide package (yum install python-pyside fails with no package available).

Is there another repo that contains this package?

Annoyingly, PyQt does exist and installs easily...

Comment: You sure? https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/repoview/python-pyside.html

Comment: Not sure (new to Linux), but that package is for CentOS 6, no?  I'm looking for CentOS 7 install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not see any official packages for this in any of the normal CentOS repositories so you'll likely have to download the source package and attempt to rebuild it yourself.

I would start with the Fedora 21 version of the package available here:

- http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/development/21/source/SRPMS/p/python-pyside-1.2.2-2.fc21.src.rpm

Once downloaded you can use `rpmbuild` to rebuild it, assuming you have the necessary compilation environment stood upon a CentOS 7 system.

Comment: Thanks for verifying.  Building the RPM requires generatorrunner-devel, which also doesn't exist in the CentOS 7 repo.  I think it'll probably be easiest to rebuild pyside myself, or maybe even rebuild the app in PyQT

Comment: buiding from source was surprisingly painless- for others, clone the BuildScripts repo and build using that (instructions here http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_PySide_on_Linux)

Answer (score 2):

There is no "python-pyside" package in EPEL 7:
http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/repoview/letter_p.group.html

I have solved this with pip install, however you may need to install some prerequisites first.

1) install RPM packages:

```
qt-devel
cmake
python-devel
python-pip
```

2) if you qmake program is not "/usr/bin/qmake" you may need to do something like this:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/qmake-qt4 /usr/bin/qmake
```

3) install pyside via pip (this will take some time for build to complete):

```
sudo pip install pyside
```

Comment: This: `sudo yum install qt-devel cmake python-devel python-pip` gives this error: `Error: Unable to find a match: qt-devel python-devel python-pip`

Comment: @Frank, This answer was written for CentOS 7. Which OS and which version are you using?